# TeamCity NuGet private feed - Credentials

Tags: teamcity

I installed TeamCity and enabled NuGet server, both Authenticated Feed and Public Feed.

When I try to push packages to the server with the following command:

```
> nuget push package.nupkg [API-Key-here] -s http://myserver/httpAuth/app/nuget/v1/FeedService.svc/
```

I get the following prompt:

```
Please provide credentials for: http://myserver/httpAuth/app/nuget/v1/FeedService.svc/
```

And asks me for both "UserName" and "Password". I've tried entering credentials for TeamCity administrator and Windows administrator, but nothing works.

So I tried pushing to the Public Feed with the following command:

```
> nuget push package.nupkg [API-Key-here] -s http://myserver/guestAuth/app/nuget/v1/FeedService.svc/
```

Then I get the following:

```
Failed to process request. 'Method Not Allowed'.
The remote server returned an error: (405) Method Not Allowed..
```

Regarding the Authenticated Feed, **what credentials are they** and where do I specify them and why is the Public Feed not working?

Comment: I'm chasing the same problem right now.  Did you find any relief?

Comment: No unfortunately nothing. I stopped going through TeamCity external NuGet repository and instead I'm pushing the package straight to Octopus Deploy.

Answer (score 2):

With your first method, you might have to add `Basic HTTP` into the list of Authentication Modules in TeamCity Settings: Administration --> Authentication.

I was just trying to consume the nuget feed that TeamCity provides and this worked for me.